# How can I push all but one view in a vertical chain to the top, and the last view to the bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have a set of three buttons in a vertical chain in a ConstraintLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_2" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This looks like this:
[image: 3 buttons incorrect]

How can I use features of the ConstraintLayout to make it appear like this, while still preserving the chain?
[image: 3 buttons correct]

I have tried using the various bias settings, but they only take effect under the `packed` chain mode, and then only on the whole chain. Is it possible to individually bias the positions of the views within a chain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea to achieve this is to add a `Space` helper view as a part of the chain that will take up all the remaining unused space as necessary. Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_1" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/space" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Work perfectly.

Comment: Very nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

[image]Here is your need, You should remove below from button_3

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button_2"
```

and have to add below

```
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
```

Comment: Sorry, but that breaks the chain. The chain is important because it prevents overlapping views.

Comment: nothing breaks here, as in relative layout align_parent_buttom like wise in constraint layout we can mention parent as bottom then it takes as you need

Comment: While these views are obviously small enough that nothing breaks, my production code does have a chance of breaking due to user-entered content. If the middle button was instead a multiline EditText, a user could overflow the UI.

Comment: we cannot conclude this without real requirement. If possible share the things

Answer (score 0):

Set the chain with a style of `packed` with a vertical bias of `0`. That will place the three views at the top. To move the bottom view to the bottom of the screen, you will need to set a top margin on the bottom view. Since the margin will vary by device and orientation, you will need to set it programmatically.

Unfortunately, if the middle view can expand vertically as with a multi-line `EditText` that you mention, then setting the margin will still work, but you will need to make adjustments as the middle view expands. This is all doable but a little involved.